# Vim copying the line numbers?

Tags: vim, copy, copy-paste

I am using vim through and SSH connection.  I have the numbers setting set, and so when ever I try to copy sections of my code with the mouse...it grabs the numbers also.  Is there a good way to copy text that doesn't grab the numbers with it.  (I know that with in that instance of vim I can use Y, but I need a way to copy to other instances and programs).

Here's an example of what I am talking about.

```
1 function foo ( home, ip, hash, regex )
2 {
3 return false;
4 }
```

Thank you all very much for the advice.

Comment: do you have your `mouse` set? what does `:set mouse?` returns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:set nonumber
```

copy what you want

```
:set number
```

[:help number](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27number%27)

Comment: That would work, I am kind of looking for a way that doesn't involve turning of the numbers if possible though.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible; maybe someone else will have a better suggestion.

Comment: Ok turns out that, because I was using it in terminal, it was throwing off some settings.  This, in conjunction with setting the paste mode however did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Toggle the `'number'` setting with a `!`

```
:set nu!
```

Run it once to turn off `'number'`. Run the command again to turn the setting back on.

I use the following mapping in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <leader>tn :set nu! nu?<cr>
```

It will toggle the setting and then echo out the current value of `'number'`

For more help see:

```
:h 'nu'
:h :set-!
```

Comment: The problem I am having is even once this setting is toggled it actually copies worse for me for some reason.  The indentations accumulate and it gets pretty nasty.

Answer (score 6):

- If you copy and paste within Vim, there is no valid reason to not use the proper commands: `y` to "yank" (copy, see `:help y`) and `p` to "put" (paste, see `:help p`).
- If you copy in remote Vim to paste in another local app, you'll have to:

  ```
  :set nonumber
  do your thing
  :set number
  ```

  You might want to verify if you are able to use "X11 Forwarding" as [it enables two-way clipboard sharing.](https://defuse.ca/blog/2012/04/clipboard-over-ssh-with-vim/)
- If you copy in a local app to paste in remote Vim, you'll have to:

  ```
  copy in local app
  go to Vim
  :set paste
  Ctrl+v or Cmd+v
  :set nopaste
  ```

  See `:help pastetoggle` for a handy mapping.