# How can I avoid copying line numbers to my clipboard from vim?

Tags: vim, mouse, clipboard, copy-paste, multiline

I like having numbers and relative numbers set in my vim, but I want to be able to select text without grabbing the line numbers.

[image]

Were I to paste this text with ctrl-v it would contain the line numbers which is not what I want.

```
  8 Plug 'michal-h21/vim-zettel'
  7 Plug 'mattn/calendar-vim'
  6 call plug#end()
  5 
  4 let wiki_1 = {}
  3 let wiki_1.path = '~/vimwiki/'
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482187/vim-copying-the-line-numbers) does not have a solution. I want to be able to select the text with my mouse without typing additional settings into the vim window before copying.

So, without changing settings mid-operation, is there a way to grab just the text and put it on my clipboard?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to do so with the mouse, you have to ask that to your terminal.

I use URxvt, for instance, and I can select a rectangle of text as I like by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> while I click and then move the mouse, so I can just avoid selecting the numbers:
[image]

---

A better option is to become aware of the registers `+` (clipboard) and `*` (primary selection) and make use of them. (See [`:help quote+`](https://vimhelp.org/gui_x11.txt.html#quote%2B), [`:help registers`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#registers) and other pages linked from there.)

For instance, if you want to copy lines from 5 to 10 (the exact lines you have highlighted in your screenshot), you would move to line 5, e.g. via <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to store them in the clipboard; afterwards, you can paste the content of the clipboard in other programs via a combo specific to that program, often <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>.

Comment: [How can I send just-yanked text to the clipboard?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38242/how-can-i-send-just-yanked-text-to-the-clipboard), while not the subject of OPs question, nonetheless has a lot of useful answers/comments around some the `+` and `*` clipboards.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP, except I'm ssh'd onto a remote server, and my local computer does not have access to the remote vim registers. To fix this, on the occasion i need to copy something onto by local pc's register, I simply `:set nonumber` do my copying, then `:set number` again. But it's really annoying. I wish there was a plugin to fix this issue

Answer (score 3):

### First problem: selecting text without line numbers

Your terminal emulator can't tell a line number from genuine buffer content so you can't rely on it to be smarter than you about what it copies. FWIW, you would have the same problem with vertical window separators, the fold column, etc.

If you *absolutely* need to select text with your mouse, then you should set the `:help 'mouse'` option in your `vimrc`. A good, general purpose, value would be `a`:

```
set mouse=a
```

This has the effect of disabling your terminal emulator's mouse handling to let Vim, which knows where line numbers are, control it.

### Second problem: yanking the selected text to system clipboard

You can check if your Vim was built with clipboard support with:

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

A `1` means that you have clipboard support and that you should be able to do `"+y` or `"*y` on the selected text. `"+y` yanks to the system clipboard (like `Ctrl-c`/`Ctrl-v`/etc.) and `"*y` is X11's primary selection (right click, etc.). If you feel those two extra keystrokes are too much, see `:help 'clipboard'`.

A `0` means that you don't have clipboard support and that you should get a different package. Which one and how depends on your operating system.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment; set mouse=a makes it so I can't copy the highlighed text with the keyboard, but the highlighted text avoids the line numbers